# How to get the bounds of a GeoJSON file in GeoPandas as a seperate file?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I am trying to generate a polygon which circumscribes all shapes in the given GeoJSON (could be either point, line, or polygon shapes).

I figured out how to do this with [bounding boxes](https://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.total_bounds) (`.total_bounds`). This is not an optimal solution and I am looking for a minimum area that covers all the shapes within the GeoJSON.

```
import shapely
bound = shapely.geometry.box(*input_json.total_bounds).buffer(buffer_dist)
bound = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.GeoSeries(bound), columns=['geometry'])
bound = bound.set_crs(input_json.crs)
```

How can I generate a polygon which contains all shapes within the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) - [`GeoSeries.convex_hull`](https://geopandas.org/geometric_manipulations.html#GeoSeries.convex_hull).

```
import geopandas as gpd

for f in ('/tmp/testpoint.geojson', '/tmp/testline.geojson', '/tmp/testpoly.geojson'):
    gdf = gpd.read_file(f)
    hull = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.GeoSeries(gdf['geometry'].unary_union.convex_hull))
    hull.set_crs(gdf.crs)
    hull.to_file(f.replace('.geojson', '_hull.shp'))
```

Here's the output for a convex hull of the points:

[image]

Lines:

[image]

Polys:

[image]